# Why would onload event not reference a form element?

Tags: onload, document-body

I have inherited a legacy web application that requires an update to consume a new set of asset inspection photos.
My issue is that the body tag has an onload event which references and populates a select form element (cChg) in the existing application. When I take a copy of the html page and edit it to reference a new network share, the onload event does not reference the select form element and returns a null reference.

I do not understand why the existing web application would correctly reference the select form element, but running the html page after making edits would not.

What am I missing here?

```html
<HTML>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function imageLoad() {
      dts = "Capture Date/Time: XXX";
      document.getElementById('mdt').innerHTML = dts;
      var list = document.getElementById('cChg');
      val = 0;
      str = "0m to 100m";
      list.options[list.options.length] = new Option(str, val);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="imageLoad();">
  <div id="imgbox"></div>
  <form name="frmCtrls">
    <table width="970px">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button type="button" name="cBtnPlay" title="Play"></button>
          <button type="button" name="cBtnStop" title="Stop"></button>
        </td>
        <td align="right">
          <select name="cSpeed">
                        <option value="900">Very Slow</option>
                        <option value="700">Slow</option>
                    </select>
          <select name="cChg">
                        <option value="0" selected="selected">Please Select</option>
                    </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  <table width="970px">
    <tr>
      <td>Click the image</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span id="mdt"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the select element only has a name parameter, not an id parameter.

When I reference the select element with document.getElementById('cChg');, an element with that id cannot be found and returns null.

The solution is to add an id parameter to the select element definition, i.e. select id='cChg'>.

I still do not understand why the existing web application correctly references the select element (without an id parameter), but I have a solution to be able to make the edits I need and update the html page.